# How do I dynamically import a function by its pythonic path?

Tags: python

I have a function in a submodule that normally can be imported like this:

```
from core.somepack import my_func
```

Instead I would like to import it lazily by a given pythonic string `core.somepack.my_func`. What is the best way to do it?

```
my_func = some_function_i_am_asking_for('core.somepack.my_func')
my_func()
```

Comment: Do you mean `import core` and `my_func = core.somepack.my_func(....)`?

Comment: @TimRoberts No. I mean according to the concept of lazy import: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading

Comment: Do you mean `importlib.import_module`?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using python built-in `importlib` module.
It helps importing a module or a function at runtime when i.e the module name is not known until runtime.
Here is a sample code for having a lazy import using `importlib`:

```
import importlib

def lazy_import(fn_path):
    module_path, fn_name = fn_path.rsplit('.', 1)
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
    fn = getattr(module, fn_name)
    return fn
```

You can call the `lazy_import` function with your `'module_name.func_name'` string.